# how to remove same elements from and array in pine script

Tags: arrays, for-loop, pine-script

I have an array which contains some zeros in it , i tried this code but `label.indexof` just delete the first one

```
for i in arrayname 
    if i == 0 
        array.remove(arrayname, array.indexof(i))
```

if i don't do this my array size gets too large

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if values are zero before adding them? and if they are zero dont add? That would be best, if not you could try something like this

```
clearZero(_arr) =>
    int i = 0
    while i < array.size(_arr) and array.size(_arr) > 0 
        if array.get(_arr, i) == 0
            array.remove(_arr, i)
            continue
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thankyou, this method works , but if the array size gets bigger it gives the error that loops take too long to execute , I don't understand why for loops doesn't work

Comment: I would suggest checking for zeros and not adding them to the array in the first place